# Splitting lines into columns

Tags: sed, tr, tabular, csv

I have a problem. Right now, a file that was supposed to be tab-delimited is missing a few "newlines"... My file looks something like this right now

```
Field1 Field2 Field3
Field1 Field2 Field3 Field1 Field2 Field3 Field1 Field2 Field3
Field1 Field2 Field3 Field1 Field2 Field3
Field1 Field2 Field3
Field1 Field2 Field3 Field1 Field2 Field3
Field1 Field2 Field3
```

I want to make it look uniform, with each "field1" starting at a new line

```
Field1 Field2 Field3
Field1 Field2 Field3
Field1 Field2 Field3
Field1 Field2 Field3
Field1 Field2 Field3
```

The problem is, each of these columns has a unique set of data, so I can't find a familiar place to split it into a new line. Any help is greatly appreciated!

PS: doing this in sed or tr would be greatly appreciated
PS: there can be up to 150 columns, not just 6 or 9 or any other multiple of 3

Comment: If you can't find a place to split it, what makes you think an unintelligent splitting utility can?

Comment: Well, I was hoping there was a way to split into a new line after every third tab

Comment: But line 5 there has no separator between `Field3` and `Field1`.

Comment: Wouldn't just a few rules help?

If more than 3 columns, check if 6 or 9 columns and add new lines accordingly.

If number_of_columns % 3 is not 0 you would need a manual check?

Comment: Sorry, theres suppose to be a space, I'll change it

Comment: time to push back on your data provider. Good luck.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This might work for you:

```
sed 's/\s/\n/3;P;D' file
```

Explanation:

- The third white space character (space or tab) is replaced by a newline `s/\s/\n/3`
- The string upto the first newline is printed `P`
- The string upto the first newline is deleted `D`

  The `D` command has a split personality. If there is no newline it deletes the string and the next line is read in. If, however, a newline exists, it deletes the string upto the newline and then the cycle is started on the same string until no newlines exist.

Comment: I'll give you the best answer if you explain to me how that command works (it worked btw)

Answer (score 1):

This will work on the example you gave...

`sed -e 's/\([^\t ]* [^\t ]* [^\t ]*\)[\t ]/\1\n/g'`